# converting [AnyObject] to [Int] in swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, int, anyobject

I am trying to create an array on numbers and have the user save them on their device. However when the data is saved (by using `NSUserDefaults` method) it is converted to an `[AnyObject]` array. I need to convert it to an array of `[Int]`. Here is my current approach to this:

```
class ProgressViewController: UIViewController {
  let kUserDefault = UserDefaults.standard
  var chartData = [Int]()
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let weighting = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "chartData")
    footer1.text = "\((weighting))"
}
  @IBAction func AddGraphComponent(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var weighText:UITextField!
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter new Weight!", message: "Please enter your Weight, followed by the date in which your weight was recorded", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addTextField { (weighText) in
    weighText.placeholder = "Weight"
    weighText.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
}
alert.addTextField { (dateText) in
    dateText.placeholder = "Date (MM/YY)"
}
let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (_) in
    let field = alert.textFields![0] as? UITextField
    let weigh = alert.textFields![1] as? UITextField

        if (field?.text)! == "" || (weigh?.text)! == "" {
            let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: "Please fill in BOTH fields", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else {
            print((field?.text)!,(weigh?.text)!)
            let dataInt:Int = Int((field?.text!)!)!
            self.chartData.append(dataInt)
            self.chartLegend.append((weigh?.text)!)

            self.kUserDefault.set([self.chartData], forKey: "chartData") //as? [Int]
            self.kUserDefault.set([self.chartLegend], forKey: "chartLegend")
            self.kUserDefault.synchronize()
}
}
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(confirmAction)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

I've tried `let weightData: Int = weighting as [Int]` but it crashes saying fatal error
I've tried `print("\(weighting?[0] as! Int)")` but it crashes saying `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' (0x109f6ae88) to 'NSNumber' (0x108df0300).`

when I try

```
let weighting = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "chartData") as! [Int]
print("\((weighting[0]))")
```

my app crashes saying `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' (0x108190e88) to 'NSNumber' (0x107016300)`

is there any way to convert a saved array from `[AnyObject]` to `[String]` or `[Int]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
self.kUserDefault.set([self.chartData], forKey: "chartData")
```

you are saving an object of type `[[Int]]` since `chartData` is already an array.

Remove the brackets

```
self.kUserDefault.set(self.chartData, forKey: "chartData")
```

Comment: it still gives me the same issues.

Comment: Using the syntax above you have to flatten the array to assign the value to a text field `footer1.text = "\(weighting[0])"`. Basically you have to decide if the array is supposed to be an array of `Int` aka `[Int]` or an array of `[Int]` aka `[[Int]]`.

Comment: it actually worked after playing around with my code! Thank You!